# How can I change my Ubuntu version from LTS to the latest non-LTS release?

Tags: 20.04, updates, lts

I just installed Ubuntu Desktop and got everything setup, but I realized this is the LTS version. Is there any way to change to the latest version to ensure I get all the latest updates instead of staying on LTS or is this not possible without a re-installation?

Comment: Ubuntu has two upgrade paths, from one release to the next (ie. 20.04 to 20.10), **or** from a LTS to the next LTS (ie. 20.04 will be able to go to 22.04 **after** the release of 22.04.1).

Comment: You can *upgrade via re-install* which allows you to skip releases, otherwise 20.04 will upgrade to 20.10, then you can reboot & checkout your 20.10 system, once you know it's good perform another upgrade and reach 21.04.  FYI:  You didn't say if desktop or server, *upgrade via re-install* works best with desktop systems as some server apps store configs in system directories which are erased prior to package-install during the re-install..  Desktop configs being in $HOME aren't touched unless you select 'format' & thus clean-install.

Comment: If you want to upgrade to 21.04 then the path will be 20.04->20.10->21.04 for which go to `software and updates` then in the updates section change the setting to `notify me for any new version` and go to `Software update` and update your system after all update you will be provided with an option to upgrade to next non LTS release. The better way as said by @guiverc will be to reinstall.

Comment: This is desktop, sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: FYI:  The *upgrade via re-install* is to use *Manual Partitioning/Something-else/Manual* and select your existing partitions but do **not** format any... it causes the installer to note your installed packages, erase system directories, perform the install, then attempt to add-back your additional packages (if they're available for the new release; you get an error if some cannot be re-installed).  I *love* and test this method regularly (we QA-test it in Lubuntu, so I know it works on *hirsute*, but it's **not** a QA-test for main Ubuntu so whilst I've used it, I can't recall when last).

Comment: http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/423/builds/229820/testcases/1701/results shows a link to one of the QA-tests of what I mention (d780 box; `clementine` being software I tested for as it's not included on the Lubuntu ISO but was present & setup was correct post-install despite the re-install)..   the d755-5 test also used that option (from *testing checklist* but it's less clear from iso.qa. logs due to how written; lack of errors was the key bit as packages on prior system were re-added; again not on Lubuntu ISO)